# using "has been" for actions other then just visiting

Tags: grammar, usage

If I want to say that Jack went to Italy and is not back yet, I would say:

> He's gone to Italy.

If I want to say that Jack went to Italy and came back, I would say:

> He's been to Italy.

If I want to say that Jack went to pick up his daughter from school, I would say:

> He's gone to pick up his daughter from school.

But if I want to say that Jack went to pick up his daughter from school and came back, why can I not say:

> He's been to pick up his daughter from school.

?

Comment: "He's been to the school to pick up his daughter" How about this?

Comment: @BellaSwan - Thanks, but I would want to know the reason why I can't say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not the case that the one sentence means he's home now while the other sentence doesn't.

*He's been to Italy* doesn't mean that he came back.

We can infer that he's no longer in Italy (although this is not *always* the case), but we can't assume that he's returned from there and is home now. What if he's been on a trip around the world and is now somewhere other than either Italy *or* his home?

The same is true of *he's been to pick up his daughter from school*. Perhaps he and his daughter are now having dinner at some restaurant. There's no way of knowing where he is *now*.

---

But the actual location of where *he's been*, the purpose for him having gone there, and the length of his stay don't have any explicit impact on determining his return or current location.

Both of the *he's been* sentences *can* be interpreted in the same way—and the *school* version *can* be used to mean the same type of thing as the *Italy* version.

To make this more explicit, just add *many times* to the end of each of them:

> He's been to Italy *many times*.
>   He's been to pick up his daughter from school *many times*.

---

Note that as was mentioned in a comment under the question, it might be more natural to move the position of the last part of the *school* sentence:

> He's been to school to pick up his daughter *many times*.

However, this only changes the parsing. It doesn't actually change anything about the interpretation of where he is now (or if he returned).